# Python, difference of dict lists by comparing different fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I have two different lists with dictionaries:

```
first = [{'id': '1'}, {'id': '2'}, {'id': '3'}]

second = [{'user_id': '1'}, {'user_id': '2'}]
```

I want something like:

```
# This is pseudocode 
first (id) - second (user_id) = [{'id': '3'}]
```

Is this possible on python?

I know that it is possible by using multiple loop operators, but is there more elegant method of solving this problem, like using lambdas or something?

Comment: Do you want to compare the values or key value pairs ? Or should we just assume that keys in the first list are part of the keys in the second list ?

Comment: @BcK values of keys. Assume that you have received two jsons from different API's

Comment: Seems that you have a typo in third items of `first` list. Is that a set or dictionary?

Comment: @Kasramvd Third code block is pseudocode, I just wanted to write as "substract from first list by comparing its `id` with second lists `user_id`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a nested list comprehension as following:

```
In [9]: [d1 for d1 in first if not any(d2['user_id'] == d1['id'] for d2 in second)]
Out[9]: [{'id': '3'}]
```

But as a more Pythonic way it's better to use set operations and a list comprehension:

```
In [13]: f = {d['id'] for d in first}

In [14]: s = {d['user_id'] for d in second}

In [15]: result = [{'id': i} for i in f - s]

In [16]: result
Out[16]: [{'id': '3'}]
```

Comment: I received `TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable` error message

Comment: An `O(N²)` solution to an `O(N)` problem is many things but elegant it isn't.

Comment: @Mr.D As I mentioned in comments that's because of your third item `{'id', '3'}` you should change it to `{'id': '3'}`.

Comment: @zwer Indeed that' why I added a set-based solution. Check out the update.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach. Using a `list comprehension` and `lambda`.

```
first = [{'id': '1'}, {'id': '2'}, {'id': '3'}]
second = [{'user_id': '1'}, {'user_id': '2'}]

checkVal = map(lambda d: d['user_id'], second)
print([i for i in first if i["id"] not in checkVal])
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': '3'}]
```

Comment: An optimization note: `checkVal` should really be a `set`. Also, mapping to a lambda just to extract the `user_id` value would be many times slower than straight `set` comprehension.

Comment: I used lambda just because OP wanted to know if it is possible to use it

Comment: The question is _is there more elegant method of solving this problem_, the lambdas are mentioned as maybe being a potential solution. In my book, elegant means graciously using available resources, too.